# Controlling Forks in C

Tags: c, tree, fork

I have a C file that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
int main () 
{ 
    pid_t child_pid; 
    printf ("The PID is %d\n", (int) getpid ()); 
    child_pid = fork (); 
    if (child_pid != 0)
    { 
        printf ("this is the parent process, with PID %d\n", 
        (int)getpid()); 
        printf ("the child's PID is %d\n", (int) child_pid); 
    } 
    else 
        printf ("this is the child process, with PID %d\n", 
        (int)getpid()); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I need to modify it to produce a a hierarchy that looks like

```
parent (0)
  |
  +---> child (1)
  |
  +---> child (2)
          |
          +----> child (3)
          |
          +----> child (4)
                  |
                  +----> child (5)
                  |
```

Basically a tree structure where each second child makes two new children. As far as I understand it, when I `fork()` a process, each process will run concurrently. Adding a `fork()` in the `if` statement seems to work and creates processes 0 to 2 correctly, since only the parent will create a new fork. But I have no idea how to make process 2 fork and not 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered the limits of this process? When will it stop, and why? What will it do to the OS? (On a unix derived system consider reading the man page for `ulimit`.) Just trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, process 1 will be created by the first fork. Process 2 will be created by the fork inside the if-statement. So to let process 2 fork too, you fork again inside the if-statement if the second fork did not return 0.

An illustration:

```
if(fork) {
    // Inside process 0
    if(fork) {
        // still in process 0
    } else {
        // in process 2
        if(fork) {
          // still in process 2
        } else {
          // in prcess 3
        }
        // and so on
    }
} else {
    // Inside process 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Children get a copy of the parent's state at the time of the fork.

So if the parent has a counter or other property then the children will see the value at the time of they were forked (but not if the parent subsequently alters it).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to do it this way, but normally only the parent process performs the fork. This may be easier to design too. When you perform fork() inside a for-loop you'll have direct control over the processes created.

Please be aware that fork() is a relatively expensive operation, especially if you want to create many processes. More lightweight alternatives vfork and threads are available but I can not judge if they also fit your needs.

Comment: Any process can fork, even children. In fact, this is how fork bombs are written, with each process forking another two until the system is swamped.

Comment: It was just an exercise - I would never willingly do something so strange :)

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but an interesting one still. The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for `fork()` tells us that the return value:

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So we know that `fork()` returns a 0 to the child, we can use this as the controlling mechanism:

```
int main()
{
   // Here we're in the parent (0) process

   if(fork())  // This starts the chain, only the parent will do this
    if(!fork()) //the child will pass this, the parent will skip it
     for(count = 0; counter < number_of_processes; counter++) //now the 2nd child loops
     {
         if(fork())
             if(!fork());
         else
             break;
     }
```

Let's put some numbers to it:

```
//parent (18402)
if(fork()) // spawns 18403, parent 18402 keeps going
  if(!fork()) // spawns 18404, parent 18402 drops to the end of main()
    for(count = 0; count < number_of_processes; conter++) // 18404 enters here
      if(fork())  // 18404 forks 18405 and then goes on
        if(!fork());  // 18404 spawns 18406 before leaving, 18406 restarts the loop
        else
          break; // 18404 breaks out there
      else
          break; //18405 leaves the loop here
```

So after one iteration we have:

```
  18402
    |
    +---> 18403
    |
    +---> 18404
            |
            +----> 18405
            |
            +----> 18406
                     |
```

After this we'll keep looping two new processes, the second of which will keep iterating until you've made as many passes as are required.